# Web Api Security client and user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api

pretty new to creating Web APIs, I am currently trying to secure my API and have a couple of questions

So basically I have a Web API and an MVC app. The API currently has a controller called Account that has two methods Register and Login. The MVC app has the same controller with actions but just calls the api methods.

Now basically they way I see it, I only ever want my MVC app to use the Web API, so ill have an api key in the MVC app webconfig that gets passed to the API each time? Also users need to authenticate so at the same time passing the user details?

Will this mean I need to setup two AuthAttributes? One for a user and one for the api details?

**EDIT**

To take this example a bit further and to demonstrate what I need

I have an WebUI that has a controller called CreateTeam. This passes a Team model up to the api Controller method CreateTeam, the api method requires that the user is authorized to create a team. Now this works fine but....

I also have a controller on my api called LeaguesController, which has a method AddNewTeamsToLeagues. Now I have a console app that runs every hour that calls this method on the api to add new teams to leagues. Now I dont ever want anyone to call this method on the api, I only ever want the console app to be able to use it. Whats the best way to secure this?

Comment: are you planning to share the API to any other client? If not, there is no much need to have it

Comment: But what about in this scenario: The register method on the API can technically be accessed by any client? So someone could make an ap that could spam your web api register method? but if the register method required a valid api key, which only my mvc app knew about, they would just get returned an Authorized error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use the token generated by `[AntiForgeryValidation]` (the Razor helper is `@Html.AntiForgeryToken`). You can use the following token (generated on your MVC View) to assist with validation if you'd like (it can be very helpful) or use your own:

```
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="some-generated-value" />
```

If you're using jQuery you can override the default Ajax options (`jQuery.ajaxSetup()` - [API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/)) to automatically add this to your request headers and validate against it (in whatever implementation you want). You can also obviously send in a username and whatever else you'd like for verification uses.

Then, you can have your Web API have a filter that validates against this information (and whatever else you'd like) using `AntiForgery.Validate(cookieValue, request.Headers["__RequestVerificationToken"]);`.

Unfortunately, until MVC6/Web API3 the two controller types have completely different implementation so you may have to write a customer filter yourself to handle authentication. There are dedicated [Authorize] attributes for both MVC and Web API but they have have different namespaces (System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute vs System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute).

Hope this helps. For further reading, you can check out [this blog post](http://richiban.wordpress.com/2013/02/06/validating-net-mvc-4-anti-forgery-tokens-in-ajax-requests/).

**-- Edit to reply to your updated comment about your Console application --**

You could always create a Filter that only allows local connections, specific IP addresses, certain LDAP/AD Security Groups, etc to have access to a specific controller/controller action. In your case of a Console application you would need to decide how you'd want that to be secured; once you decide to you can go from there. So, say you want to allow only specific members of an AD Security Group to access the controller, you could throw together a filter like so:

```
namespace YourAppName.Filters
{
    public class AuthorizeADAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public string Groups { get; set; }
        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            if (base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext))
            {

                var groups = Groups.Split(',').ToList();
                var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "YourDomainHere");
                var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(
                                       context,
                                       IdentityType.SamAccountName,
                                       httpContext.User.Identity.Name);
                foreach (var group in groups)
                    if (userPrincipal.IsMemberOf(context,
                         IdentityType.Name,
                         group))
                        return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var result = new ViewResult();
                result.ViewName = "NotAuthorized";
                result.MasterName = "_Layout";
                filterContext.Result = result;
            }
            else
                base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

And then apply it to a controller or a method inside of your controller, like so:

```
[AuthorizeAD(Groups = "SecurityGroupToAuth, League Admins, Console App Group")]
public YourViewModelHere AddNewTeamsToLeagues()
{
    // do stuff
}
```

So, to answer your initial question: you'll likely need two different attributes/filters for the different types (between handling the AntiforgeryToken and then the console app). Unfortunately without knowing how your application and console application are hosted (different machines, same subnet, on the same network, etc) I can't give much more information but hopefully this helps point you in the right direction for creating your own filter/attribute(s).

Comment: Sorry for the delay; I updated my answer. Hopefully it helps.